# Unity fails to start in Ubuntu( trasformed to Kali)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unity-game-engine

I know that there are similar question but nothing I searched for worked for me.

I have a problem starting Unity in my Ubuntu 15.04 distribution that i have trasformed to Kali 2.0 using Katoolin.

I applied same update but now when i start the OS i get this error:

`unable to launch "gnome-session --session=ubuntu" X session "gnome-session --session=ubuntu" not found;falling back to default session`

The **.xsession-error.old** show this:

`: unable to launch "gnome-session --session=ubuntu" X session --- 
"gnome-session --session=ubuntu" not found; falling back to default session.
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 18 requests (18 known processed) with 0 events remaining.`

The **/usr/share/xsessions** contains this files:

`gnome.desktop  LXDE.desktop  openbox.desktop  ubuntu.desktop`

and ubuntu.desktop is the default session.
How I can solve that problem?